# Keyboard appears behind the BottomSheetModal instead of above it in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using ModalBottomSheet of material 3 library and I noticed a strange behavior when i want to type in the OutlinedTextField. That's a weird issue which i couldn't manipulate.

```
        Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Row(
            Modifier.toggleable(
                value = skipHalfExpanded,
                role = Role.Checkbox,
                onValueChange = { checked -> skipHalfExpanded = checked }
            )
        ) {
            Checkbox(checked = skipHalfExpanded, onCheckedChange = null)
            Spacer(Modifier.width(16.dp))
            Text("Skip Half Expanded State")
        }
        Button(onClick = { openBottomSheet = !openBottomSheet }) {
            Text(text = "Show Bottom Sheet")
        }
    }

// Sheet content
    if (openBottomSheet) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = { openBottomSheet = false },
            sheetState = bottomSheetState,
        ) {
            Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                Button(
                    // Note: If you provide logic outside of onDismissRequest to remove the sheet,
                    // you must additionally handle intended state cleanup, if any.
                    onClick = {
                        scope.launch { bottomSheetState.hide() }.invokeOnCompletion {
                            if (!bottomSheetState.isVisible) {
                                openBottomSheet = false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Hide Bottom Sheet")
                }
            }
            InputTextField()
        }
    }
```

[image]

Any solution would be appreciated.

UPDATE!!!!
There is an existing report on google issue tracker site.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/268380384?pli=1

Comment: please share the code

Comment: i checked in my end it's giving the same issue. I think we should have to wait for sometime, it's in very early stage.

Comment: Looks like a known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/268380384.

Comment: @MikeM. I’m aware it is a known issue, I just feel someone people might have a way out.

Comment: That's something you should've stated in the question, then.

Comment: Anybody found any way around this? need to get rid of this issue

Answer (score -3):

I haven't done this in Material3 yet; but what happens if you rearrange your implementation to look more like this?

```kotlin
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = sheetState,
    sheetContent = { YourBottomSheet() }
) {
    YourPrimaryScreen()
}
```

Comment: There is no problem with Material 2. I'm more interested in Material 3. However, material 2 has its own limitation which i am struggling with.